# JQuery onBlur event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

This question seems elementary but it doesn't matter what I do ( based on the various posts on SOV I went through ) I just cannot get this event to fire in my Devextreme app

The premise...
All I want to do is to update an existing variable's value with the text that was entered. The value of the variable gets carried over from another page.  I need to update the variable's value from the text that was written into a textbox. This is all I want to do.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="dx-field-label">Code: </div>
    <div class="dx-field-value" id="txtCode" data-bind="dxTextBox: { value: CustomerCode, placeholder: 'Enter Code', showClearButton: true }"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS code :

```
var viewModel = {
    // CustomerID: params.CustomerID,
    // CustomerName: ko.observable(params.CustomerName),
    //CustomerEmail: ko.observable(params.CustomerEmail),
    // CustomerID: ko.observable(params.CustomerID),

    Continue: function () {
        alert('Saved'); 
    },
    CustomerID: CustomerID,
    CustomerName: CustomerName,
    CustomerCode: CustomerCode,
    CustomerEmail: CustomerEmail,
    AddCustomer: AddCustomer,

    //Add Customer
};

$('#txtCode').on('blur', 'txtCode', function () {
    CustomerCode = $("#txtCode").dxTextBox('option', 'value');      
    console.log(CustomerCode);
});
```

Any advice would be appreciated

EDIT

OK, I have now done this:

```
 CustomerID;
CustomerName.trim();
CustomerCode.trim();
CustomerEmail.trim();



ko.applyBindings({
ChangedCustomerCode: ko.observable(),
CodeFocusOut: function(e){
    ChangedCustomerCode: value;
    console.log(value);
    console.log(ChangedCustomerCode);
    CustomerCode: ChangedCustomerCode;
    console.log(CustomerCode);
}
```

});

```
var viewModel = {

    Continue: function () {
        alert('Saved');

    },



    CustomerID: CustomerID,
    CustomerName: CustomerName,
    CustomerCode: CustomerCode,
    CustomerEmail: CustomerEmail,
    AddCustomer: AddCustomer,


};


return viewModel;
};
```

But it tells me that I cannot apply bindings to the same elemenet multiple times. What should I do?

Comment: When binding event, `'txtCode'`, missing `.`? OR just `$('#txtCode').on('blur', function() {`

Comment: Also Please make sure the `.txtCode` class input inside the `#txtCode`

Answer (score 1):

You try to handle the `blur` event on the 'div' element(`id="txtCode"`). But focus state of this element is not changed, so the `blur` event does not fire.

Actually, if you use knockoutjs, you should not handle the `blur` event manually. Just use ko.observables:

```
<div data-bind="dxTextBox: { value: myValue, onValueChanged: valueChanged }"></div>

ko.applyBindings({
    myValue: ko.observable(),
    valueChanged: function(e){
        alert(e.value);
    }
});
```

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/0284uz1f/2/

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sergey, but now I get the error stating That I cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. I have updated my original post with the new code

Comment: If you use the Devextreme app project template, you should not call ko.applyBindings manually. I called it because I used only knockoutjs.

Answer (score 0):

Use event binding like so:

```
$('.txtCode').on('blur', function ($this) {
    // Code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('body').on('blur', '#txtCode', function () {
     CustomerCode = $("#txtCode").dxTextBox('option', 'value');

console.log(CustomerCode);
});
```